# Convert Systemd (systemctl) file from CentOs to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, systemd

I have airflow installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I have file as follows:

```
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

[Unit]
Description=Airflow celery flower
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow flower
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have read following comment below the file.

Keep in mind that these files are configured for CentOS. If you install them in Debian, replace the EnviromentFile variable and modify path to Bash in ExecStart.

I have no experience with Linux system.

I have used above file, but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me what I should do?

airflow is located "~/airflow"

Comment: In what particular way did it "not work"? `systemctl start airflow` will show you how to run `journalctl` to see why it failed. Not having a file at `/etc/sysconfig/airflow` would be one reason, not having `/bin/airflow` would be another.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I notice is that the path to the file is not correct.

Your config file has `ExecStart=/bin/airflow flower`but in your comment you say

> airflow is located `~/airflow`

`~/` is the `/home/$user` directory for the currently logged in user.